# Authentication error connecting to smtp server via openssl

Tags: smtp, openssl, base64

My approach to this is very simple, based off several different sources online. I armored my username and password using this command:

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("\000user@example.com\000password")'
```

Here is a dump of the connection result:

```
~$ openssl s_client -connect smtp.koumbit.net:587 -starttls smtp
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = "GeoTrust, Inc.", CN = RapidSSL CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
SNIP Certificate info
---
250 DSN
ehlo riot-nrrd.info
250-bureau.koumbit.net
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 20480000
250-ETRN
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
auth plain <paste of base64 encoded output here>
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
closed
```

I know that the username and password I used were correct because they are being used by my email client. I am not terribly familiar with smtp or openssl. Particularly, I am not clear on the whether the hostname provided via EHLO is of any significance...

Things I have (blindly) tried:

- Adding `-crlf` as parameters to openssl, based on [openssl client SMTP with gmail port 587, no response (250 OK) from after <crlf>.<crlf>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4907124)

Answer (score 2):

For debugging `SMTP` transactions, you can use `swaks` tool. Please find sample output below.

```
[clement@myhost ~]$ swaks --from you@gmail.com --to someone@yahoo.com --auth-user you@gmail.com --auth-pass "your_pass" -tls --server smtp.gmail.com --port 587
=== Trying smtp.gmail.com:587...
=== Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
<-  220 mx.google.com ESMTP sy1sm38890738pab.30 - gsmtp
 -> EHLO myhost
<-  250-mx.google.com at your service, [223.233.234.250]
<-  250-SIZE 35882577
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250-STARTTLS
<-  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-  250 CHUNKING
 -> STARTTLS
<-  220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
=== TLS started w/ cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
=== TLS peer subject DN="/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=smtp.gmail.com"
 ~> EHLO myhost
<~  250-mx.google.com at your service, [223.233.234.250]
<~  250-SIZE 35882577
<~  250-8BITMIME
<~  250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
<~  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<~  250 CHUNKING
 ~> AUTH LOGIN
<~  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
 ~> <Your_base64_encoded_username>
<~  334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
 ~> <your_base64_encoded_password>
<~  235 2.7.0 Accepted
 ~> MAIL FROM:<you@gmail.com>
<~  250 2.1.0 OK sy1sm38890738pab.30 - gsmtp
 ~> RCPT TO:<someone@yahoo.com>
<~  250 2.1.5 OK sy1sm38890738pab.30 - gsmtp
 ~> DATA
<~  354  Go ahead sy1sm38890738pab.30 - gsmtp
 ~> Date: Fri, 11 Apr 2014 23:22:50 +0530
 ~> To: someone@yahoo.com
 ~> From: you@gmail.com
 ~> Subject: test Fri, 11 Apr 2014 23:22:50 +0530
 ~> X-Mailer: swaks v20120320.0 jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/
 ~> 
 ~> This is a test mailing
 ~> 
 ~> .
<~  250 2.0.0 OK 1397238779 sy1sm38890738pab.30 - gsmtp
 ~> QUIT
<~  221 2.0.0 closing connection sy1sm38890738pab.30 - gsmtp
=== Connection closed with remote host.
```

More info about the tool [here](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/)

Comment: This is what my provider suggested as well.